# pgfplots: Reduce number of minor ticks in a log log plot

Tags: pgfplots, ticks, number

I want to reduce the number of ticks in my log log plot to exactly 3. But I can't tamper with the `max space between ticks` option, otherwise I'll lose the minor ticks on the y axis.

I tried to give `max minor ticks log` but doesn't seem to do anything.
Here is my code:

```
     \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

     \usepackage{pgfplots}
     \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

     \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
         xmin=0.001,xmax=1.2,ymin=0.001,ymax=10^8, xmode=log,ymode=log,
         max space between ticks=20, max minor ticks log=3
      ]  
     \addplot[black] {0.72};
     \addplot[domain=0.001:1.2] {0.004/x^4};
     \addplot[domain=0.001:1.2] {0.276/x^3};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}

     \end{document}
```

sorry, if I haven't been clear. It's my first pgfplots macro, and I was used to TikZ, in the manual I saw that `min ticks num` sets a lower bound to the number of ticks and I improvised a max instead, of course it didn't work.

In the picture below there are 8 minor ticks for each major one, and I would like to reduce this number to 3.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a complete example, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. And please explain where the minor ticks should be (frankly, I would be very confused if I would not see 9 minor ticks, but OK, you're the boss ;-), and whether you invented `max minor ticks log=3`.

Comment: minor ticks should be in correspondence of 2.5e , 5e, 7.5e at each power of 10.